# Get Already Consoled Text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, console

**Use Case:**
I want to get console data via javascript as if there is any text on console, we want to capture it.

I've explored many solutions but with them, we can get console data after our implentation. I want to get console data that has been done before our implementation like:

```js
console.log('Bilal Riaz')
// Our implementation of code to get Bilal Riaz
```

not for this(as many solutions do):

```js
// Our implementation of code to get Bilal Riaz
console.log('Bilal Riaz')
```

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:node.js]. So you're trying to do this in Node.js, **not** in a browser?

Comment: EDITED. I'm trying to add a script to the existing website.

Comment: it's not perfectly clear but did you mean to just override the console.log function with your own? if that's the case just look for that search string (override console.log) or start by doing something like `const originalLog = console.log; console.log = ()=>{ /*capture arguments here*/ return originalLog(arguments);}`